# Angular2 Two mouse events

Tags: angular, typescript

Looking for an Angular2 solution to this problem iv'e been trying to solve.

I need to handle two use-cases on a calendar of cells.
First use case is simple Click the cell -> adds that date obj to a new array.
Second use case is a little more tricky, if the user clicks and then drags his mouse along cells, a new date obj is pushed into the array for each cell he's clicked/dragged into. As far as i'm aware this can only be done by running TWO mouse events at the same-time (MouseMove and MouseDown) but i can't figure out away to get angular 2 to check both simultaneously. please help

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered noselect">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let dateName of dateNames"><span class="date-name">{{dateName}}</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
      <td class="" *ngFor="let col of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"
          (click)="dateSelect(calendar[row-1][col-1])"
          [class.info]="dateSelected(calendar[row-1][col-1])"
          >
        <span class="pull-right"
              [class.text-success]="isCurrentMonth(calendar[row-1][col-1])">
          {{displayDay(calendar[row-1][col-1])}}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!--<td *ngFor="let number of numbers">{{number}}</td>-->
</table>
```

Comment: If you drag you have a [dragstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart) event and this is easy to distinguish from click.

Comment: dragenter wont work unforuntatly, i tried it but i need the event to re-fire
every new cell i drag into drag-enter just fires once i believe

That way each new cell i drag into pushes a new object into the array